# Converting a CSV to a specific json format and output a random row

Tags: php, json, csv

I used to store the data in a text format and used PHP to get a random line in the file and convert it to JSON. The code was as follow:

```
<?php
  // open the text file
  $Textfile   = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
  // get a random line
  $rand   = mt_rand(0, count($Textfile)-1);
  // set content title
  $title = "Same Title";
  // set a random content
  $content = $Textfile[$rand];
  // result
  $result = array('content'   => $content,
                  'title'     => $title);
  // set header
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // print the random quote
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

The **Json** output is :

```
{"content":"some random content from a book","title":"Same Title"}
```

But I am adding more books so I decided to create the file in CSV format. The CSV has the following structure:

```
ID  | title              | content          |  page
1   | some unique title  | some content     |  25
2   | some other title   | some other cont  |  12
```

so the desired output will be :

```
{"ID":"1", "title":"some unique title", "content":"some content", "page", "25"}
```

I tried to use my existing php code and simply open the csv instead of the text file:

```
<?php
  // read the csv file
  $file="newformat.csv";
  $csv= file_get_contents($file);
  // create the array
  $array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
  $json = json_encode($array);

  // set header
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  // print 
  echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

but this does not give the same output as the one before and I am not sure how to implement the random row.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the .csv file contents, splits it into lines, gets a random line number, parses that line from CSV, and assigns the values to the desired keys, and then JSON-encodes it.

```
<?php
  const KEYS = ['ID', 'title', 'content', 'page'];

  $file = 'newformat.csv';
  $csv = file_get_contents($file);
  $lines = explode("\n", $csv);
  $num = count($lines);

  $randomLineNumber = rand(0, $num - 1); // get random line number
  $line = $lines[$randomLineNumber];     // get random line
  $array = array_combine(KEYS, str_getcsv($line)); // map values to keys

  header('content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your response, after uploading this to the server, I get error 500. After checking the error logs, I noticed this `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '['  ... index.php on line 2`

Comment: You may be running an older version of PHP.  You can try replacing this line:
`const KEYS = ['ID', 'title', 'content', 'page'];`
with:
`$keys = array('ID', 'title', 'content', 'page');`
and this line:
`$array = array_combine(KEYS, str_getcsv($line));`
with this:
`$array = array_combine($keys, str_getcsv($line));`

Comment: the problem is that I get "false" some times. I tried to change `randomLineNumber (rand(1, $num);` but still when randomly outputing json I get false

Comment: Does your CSV file have empty lines?

Comment: You can use http://csvlint.io to validate your CSV file.  It might also be a good idea to `explode` on the `PHP_EOL` constant instead of `"\n"`, so `explode(PHP_EOL, $csv)`.

Comment: @jpect it says it is valid